# VS Code extensions recurring issues problems - on jupyter and github copilot chat

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, github-copilot, vscode-remote-ssh

I experience problems on my VS Code, the issues are related to the extensions: Jupyter and GitHub Copilot Chat, issues are recurring together and are solved temporarily by the same steps.

On GitHub Copilot Chat: the issue is that once a day or two the extension icon on the Activity Bar (left) disappears. On the extension tab, it says 'reload required', reload doesn't solve a thing, and still appears as 'reload required'. The only way to solve it is by 'Switch to Release/Pre-Release version' and then the 'reload required' disappears.

On Jupyter extension: I'm using a Jupyter notebook in VS Code, and once every few days, the kernel is being detached and I need to "Select a Kernel" (sometimes happens during coding and active work on notebook). Then when trying to select a kernel it doesn't find the installed kernels:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoSNG.png)

Only a 'Switch to Release/Pre-Release version' solve it.

As the GitHub Copilot Chat extension, the Jupyter also says 'reload required' but no number or reloads is enough to make the badge of 'reload required' to disappear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpRDk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l40vr.png)

Important thing to note is that I'm using a remote interpreter configured through an ssh connection, which means the extensions are also installed on the remote linux machine.

My question is: what causes this issue and how to stop it from recurring?

I tried 'reload', I tried 'switch version', I made sure the extensions are updated and that are installed on the remote linux (through SSH) as required (updated as well).